# Effect of ambient fluid on a pinhole camera's intrinsic parameters

Tags: optics, camera

Suppose I am performing calibration of a pinhole camera under the Brown–Conrady distortion model and find the focal length $(f_x, f_y)$, principal point $(c_x, c_y)$, radial distortion coefficients $K_i$, and tangential distortion coefficients $P_i$.

I repeat the calibration process in air and in fresh water, in identical camera housings.

Would any of the intrinsic camera parameters change between the two calibrations? For example, would the focal length or radial distortion be affected by the refractive index of the water?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Perspective and non-perspective camera models in underwater imaging — overview and error analysis" (2011; [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-34091-8_10)), Anne Sedlazeck and Reinhard Koch explain that,

> When using the perspective model on underwater images captured through a glass port, a calibration based on above-water images is invalid underwater. Furthermore, **the perspective model itself is
> invalid for underwater images** due to the non-single view point.

That said, the pinhole model can *approximate* the effects of refraction, as discussed in "Camera Calibration Techniques for Accurate Measurement Underwater" (2019; [PDF](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-030-03635-5_2.pdf), [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-03635-5_2); [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)) by Mark Shortis:

> #### 2.3.2 Absorption of Refractive Effects
>
> In the underwater environment the effects of refraction must be corrected or modelled to obtain an accurate calibration. The entire light path, including the camera lens, housing port and water medium, must be considered. By far the most common approach is to correct the refraction effects using absorption by the physical camera calibration parameters.
>
> Assuming that the camera optical axis is approximately perpendicular to a plane or dome camera port, **the primary effect of refraction** through the air-port and port-water interfaces will be radially symmetric around the principal point (Li et al. 1996). This primary effect **can be absorbed by the radial lens distortion component of the calibration parameters.**
>
> There will also be some small, asymmetric effects caused by, for example, **alignment errors** between the optical axis and the housing port, and perhaps non-uniformities in the thickness or material of the housing. These secondary effects **can be absorbed by calibration parameters such as the decentring lens distortion and the affinity term**.

(Emphasis and line breaks added for readability.)

Shortis provides figures comparing radial and decentering distortion from in-air and in-water calibrations of a GoPro HERO4, reproduced at the end of this answer.

While "the absorption approach has the distinct advantage that it can be used with any type of underwater housing," he notes that fundamentally, the camera model is flawed for in-water distortion:

> The disadvantage of the absorption approach for the refractive effects is that there will always be some systematic errors which are not incorporated into the model. **The effect of refraction invalidates the assumption of a single projection centre for the camera** (Sedlazeck and Koch 2012), **which is the basis for the physical parameter model**. The errors are most often manifest as scale changes when measurements are taken outside of the range used for the calibration process.

The subsequent section "2.3.3 Geometric Correction of Refraction Effects" describes alternative models.

---

For more conversion between in-air and *approximate* in-water calibration, see "On the Calibration of Underwater Cameras" by J. G. Fryer and C. S. Fraser (1986; [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1477-9730.1986.tb00539.x)) or "Underwater Camera Calibration" by J.M. Lavest, G. Rives, and J.T. Lapresté (2000; [PDF](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-45053-X_42.pdf), [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45053-X_42)).

---

[image: Comparison of radial lens distortion from in-air and in-water calibrations of a GoPro Hero4 camera operated in HD video mode]
[image: Comparison of decentring lens distortion from in-air and in-water calibrations of a GoPro Hero4 camera operated in HD video mode]

| Camera | GoPro HERO4 #1 |  |  | GoPro HERO4 #2 |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Parameter | In-air | In-water | Ratio | In-air | In-water | Ratio |
| $c_x$ (mm) | 0.080 | 0.071 | 0.88 | -0.032 | -0.059 | 1.82 |
| $c_y$ (mm) | -0.066 | -0.085 | 1.27 | -0.143 | -0.171 | 1.20 |
| *f* (mm) | 3.676 | 4.922 | 1.34 | 3.658 | 4.898 | 1.34 |
| Affinity | -6.74e-03 | -6.71e-03 | 1.00 | -6.74e-03 | -6.84e-03 | 1.01 |